# Sequence diagram when to use named class "book:Book" vs anonymous ":Book" and Underlines

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

When do I use named objects like "book:Book" vs ":Book". Most books have both in a single diagram. Is there sometimes I *should* use named and others anonymous?

Then also, what do the Underline represent I remember reading it somewhere ...

Comment: `:Book` usually means an arbitrary instance of book, point being the specific instance isn't relevant.  `book:Book` usually means the instance identity is significant in some way.  For example, imagine adding two books to an order.  You might name them `book1` and `book2` so you can differentiate them.

hth.

Comment: @sfinnie, you could post that as an answer then I can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested :-)

:Book usually means an arbitrary instance of book, point being the specific instance isn't relevant. book:Book usually means the instance identity is significant in some way. For example, imagine adding two books to an order. You might name them book1 and book2 so you can differentiate them.

hth.